# How to keep popup text open after setInterval in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, dom-events, console.log

**DESCRIPTION**: I have written  Javascript code (I just got started) which queries the [Opensky](https://opensky-network.org/) [REST API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html) every 10 seconds. After I collect the data, I plot it through Leaflet.js. For each item I add a popup text box which opens when I click on the tooltip.
So far the code works great!
Here is the code so you can play around:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
            crossorigin="">
        </script>
        <style>
            #openskyMap { 
                height: 800px; 
                width:1200px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>
            "FETCH JSON from API and map lat lon"
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Where are the flights</h1>
        <p>Last Update (UNIX time): <span id="ts"></span></p>

        <div id="openskyMap"></div>

        /*                           JAVASCRIPT CODE BEGINS HERE                             */ 
        <script>

            /* DEFINE OPENSKY API URL */
            var opensky_url = "https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?time=TIME";

            /* INITIATE LEAFLET MAP */
            const mymap = L.map('openskyMap').setView([45, 0], 3);
            const attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreatMap</a> contributors'
            const tileUrl = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
            const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution});
            var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);
            tiles.addTo(mymap);

            /* CHANGE ICON SIZE BASED ON ZOOM */
            mymap.on('zoomend', function(e) {
                var currentZoom = mymap.getZoom();
                console.log("Current Zoom" + " " + currentZoom);
                if (currentZoom >= 10) {
                damsRadius = 100;
                } else {
                damsRadius = 20000;
                }
            });

            /* FUNCTION TO GET THE ICAO24 CODE. I CANNOT GET IT OUT OF HERE THOUGH! */
            function getIcao24(e) {
                var popup = e.target.getPopup();
                var content = popup.getContent();
                console.log(content)
                return content
            }

            /* INITIATE QUERY FUNCTION */
            async function getOpensky() {

                /* CALCULATE UNIX TIME TO BE PASSED TO THE URL */
                var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
                ts = ts.toString();

                /* MAKE QUERY TO OPENSKY URL */
                const  response = await fetch(opensky_url.replace('TIME',ts));
                const data = await response.json();

                /* PLOT ITEMS TO MAP USING LEAFLET:js */
                layerGroup.clearLayers();
                for (var key in data.states) {

                    /* GET SINGLE ITEM FROM JSON */
                    const item = data.states[key];

                    try{ 

                       /* GET GEOGRAPHICAL COORDINATES*/
                        const lon = item[5];
                        const lat = item[6];

                        /* DEFINE POPUP TEXT TO BE DISPLAYED*/
                        const popupText = "<p>"+item[0] + " - " + item[1] + "<br/>Lat: " + lat.toFixed(2)+" / Lon: "+lon.toFixed(2)+"<br/>Epoch: "+ts+"</p>";

                        /* ADD ITEM TO THE MAP. CALL getICAO24 FUNCTION BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SAVE THE OUTPUT*/
                        L.circle(L.latLng(
                            parseFloat(item[6]), // lon
                            parseFloat(item[5])  // lat
                        ), damsRadius).addTo(layerGroup).bindPopup(popupText).on('click', getIcao24);

                        document.getElementById('ts').textContent = ts;
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                }               

            }
            /* CALL FUNCTION FIRST TIME*/
            getOpensky();

            /* UPDATE FUNCTION EVERY 10 SECONDS */
            setInterval(getOpensky, 10000);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PROBLEM**: every time I click on an aircraft (*item*), the popup window opens as expected. However, I would like to keep the selected popup text open even after the refresh has occurred (*setInterval* every 10 seconds). This is not happening due to the fact that when I click on the tooltip, the output is only displayed on the console but not store anywhere to be somehow recognized during the next query.

**MY TENTATIVE**: I though that one possible solution is to add a function called *getIcao24* which should return the popup text and get the unique *icao24* code (*item[0]*) from the string and then check when it appears in the next iteration and set the popup box as open. However I have no clue how to get such information out of the function.

**QUESTION**: Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal? i.e. maintain the popup box of a clicked item open even after a refresh has occurred?

Comment: Consider that every time `getOpensky` is called the popup you want to store, display and keep open will have different information as in every refresh data is changed. So what is the meaning of keeping information that instantly change after 10s in the end?

Comment: Because i want to show how the content of the popup changes every iteration for a given item